# How to Convert serializedObject to UL (unordered list)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Anyone knows how to convert the output from this code into an unordered list?

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
        return false;
    });
});
```

The code above outputs for example like this:

```
{"costPerDay":"20","numberOfDays":"20","designCost":"40","cmsIntegration":"64","seoContentStrategy":"75"}
```

I was hoping if there's a way to make it output into an unordered list?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your desired result is supposed to look like, but either way you can just iterate over your object:

```js
// let obj = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject())
let obj = {"costPerDay":"20","numberOfDays":"20","designCost":"40","cmsIntegration":"64","seoContentStrategy":"75"};

$("#result").empty().append("<ul></ul>");
for (const entry in obj){
    $("#result > ul").append(`<li>${entry}: ${obj[entry]}</li>`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Or if you prefer a single-liner:

```js
$("#result").empty().append(
    "<ul>" + Object.entries(obj).map(e => `<li>${e[0]}: ${e[1]}`).join("") + "</ul>"
);
```

Working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/7a5xjwbh/

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to try your script :)

Comment: I tried, though but it seems to not work, or i just don't know where to put the single liner you did, maybe this will help, here's the source of the code that i am going to use:  http://jsfiddle.net/JOEHOELLER/217m94fk/2/

Comment: @ArchieValderrosa http://jsfiddle.net/my6ud720/

Comment: Thank you so much NullDev, that helped me a lot. there's one issue I hope you won't get mad at me, as i was checking by clicking the submit button multiple times, an instance of list appeared, which should not supposed to happen. is there away to get rid of that? try clicking the submit button multiple times in the fiddle you sent, you'll see what i mean :)

Comment: @ArchieValderrosa Fixed it by adding an `.empty()`: http://jsfiddle.net/7a5xjwbh/ - If this did indeed resolve your problem, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer :) I also edited this post to include the new versions + demo.

Comment: This is working Great! thank you so much.

Comment: Hi NullDev, Is it possible to add a Shortcode from contact form 7  along the append list that you made?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code you made does not work, maybe this will help you better figure out what i am aiming for, attached is the full code that I wanted the output as "Unordered List" and the source in CodePen http://jsfiddle.net/JOEHOELLER/217m94fk/2/ If you want to check out the working Range Slider. Thanks

```
function proRangeSlider(sliderid, outputid, colorclass) {
        var x = document.getElementById(sliderid).value;  
        document.getElementById(outputid).innerHTML = x;
        document.getElementById(sliderid).setAttribute('class', colorclass);
        
        updateTotal();
}

var total = 0;
function updateTotal() {
        var list= document.getElementsByClassName("range");
        [].forEach.call(list, function(el) {
            console.log(el.value);
            total += parseInt(el.value);
        }); 
        document.getElementById("n_total").innerHTML = total;
      
}
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
        return false;
    });
});
```